# NOT NULL constraint failed: shop_review.item_id

Tags: python, django, database, web, server

```
def order(request, item_id):
item = get_object_or_404(Item, pk=item_id)
if request.method == "POST":
    username = None
    username = request.user.username
    userInfo = username + '/' + request.POST["nameNum"]
    userAddr = request.POST["address"]
    new_order = Review.objects.create(
        reviewText = userInfo,
        votes = userAddr
    )
    return HttpResponse("<script>alert('" + userInfo + '/ ' + userAddr + "');</script> 등록 완료")
return render(request, 'order.html', {'item': item})
```

This is my views.py, and

```
class Item(models.Model):
def __str___(self):
    return self.item_name
item_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
item_text = models.CharField(max_length=300)
pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
item_amount = models.CharField(max_length=99999999)
item_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='image/', blank=True)
item_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

this is my models.py.

And when I run this part, **NOT NULL constraint failed: shop_review.item_id** << this error occurs.
How can I fix this error?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3Zx0.png)

Answer (score 1):

The review you are creating has *no* reference to its item, hence the error, you should specify the item id with:

```
new_order = Review.objects.create(
    reviewText = userInfo,
    votes = userAddr,
    item_id=item_id
)
```

It might however be a good idea to make use of a [**`Form`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/) to validate and clean the data. Right now there is no guarantee that the `request.POST` will contain an `address` for example.

---

> **Note**: In case of a successful POST request, you should make a [**`redirect`**
> [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)
> to implement the [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).
> This avoids that you make the same POST request when the user refreshes the
> browser.